# Determining the condition number in terms of relative condition number

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, numerical-methods

I have a problem of evaluating the function $f(x)=0$ if $x=0$ and $f(x)=(\ln\frac{1}{x})^\frac{-1}{7}$ if $0<x<1$. I have to determine of the problem is ill or well conditioned. I think I have to use the relative condition number.

Since this is a scalar problem, $y=f(x)$. So if $\frac{|f'(x)|}{|f(x)|}$ is the relative condition number, I have calculated it to be $$|\frac{1}{7x}\frac{1}{\ln x}|$$

Now what next? What to say about the problem's conditionality?

Comment: You are concerned about the behavior at $x=0$. What is the limit of the relative condition number as $x\to0$?

Comment: @whpowell96 it becomes $\infty$, right?

Comment: Hint: When $f(x)=0=x$ the condition number has the following formula $k_f(x)=|f'(x)|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ be an open interval. The *relative* condition number of a function $f : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ at a point $x \in I$ for which $f(x) \not = 0$ is given by $$\kappa_f(x) = \underset{\epsilon \rightarrow 0_+}{\lim} \kappa_f(x,\epsilon),$$ where $$\kappa_f(x,\epsilon) = \underset{\epsilon>0}{\sup} \left\{ \frac{1}{\epsilon}\frac{|f(x+\Delta x) - f(x)|}{|f(x)|} \: : \: |\Delta x| \leq \epsilon |x|\right\}.$$
In the event that $f$ is differentiable at $x \in I$, we have the simplification $$\kappa_f(x) = \left|\frac{x f'(x)}{f(x)}\right|.$$
In the given case, we have $I = (0,1)$ and $f(x) = (-\ln x)^{a}$, where $a \not = 0$. It follows that $f'(x) = -a(-\ln(x))^{a-1}x^{-1}$. Therefore $$\kappa_f(x) = |a||\ln(x)|^{-1}$$ for $x \in I$. We conclude that $$\kappa_f(x) \rightarrow 0, \quad x \rightarrow 0, \quad x \in I.$$ We see that $f$ is well-conditioned for all sufficiently small $x \in I$.